# VB Macro Issue for relinking Word Documents

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble getting this macro to work. I am working on a Windows 10 computer with Office 2013. The code was not written by me and I have limited knowledge in VB. The marco is supposed to update a a word document's links by mirroring how the the previous word document was linked. Below is the code, if anyone could help that would be great.

```
Sub relinking()

Dim oriacro As String
Dim taracro As String
Dim path As String

oriacro = InputBox(Prompt:="please enter the original agency acronym.", Title:="ENTER THE ORIGINAL AGENCY ACRONYM")
taracro = InputBox(Prompt:="please enter the target agency acronym.", Title:="ENTER THE TARGET AGENCY ACRONYM")
path = InputBox(Prompt:="please enter the target path.", Title:="ENTER THE TARGET PATH")

Excel.Application.Quit
'close all the excel files.(excel reference has to be activated in tool->reference'

For x = 1 To ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
'the program runs over all the linked fields'

If Left(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNam e, Len(oriacro)) = oriacro Then
'read all the fields that has "original agency acronym" in the beginning of its linked excel files.'
ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = path & "\" & taracro & "_" & Right(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNa me, Len(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceName ) - InStr(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNa me, "_"))
'Assign the fields with new links that are created from combining the "target path" ,"target agency acronym", and the parts of the names right after the original acronyms of the original linked file names.'
Else
'Leave other linked fields as they are.'
End If
Next x

MsgBox ("All Fields have been relinked!")
End Sub
```

Comment: `marco`? Macro, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

1) few typos in the above code which might just be formatting on StackOverflow: `.SourceNam e` a couple times. Also in the function which makes the new path:

```
Right(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNa me, Len(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceName ) - InStr(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNa me, "_")).
```

Also add a string variable and catch one of them in a msgbox to test:

```
If Left(ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceNam e, Len(oriacro)) = oriacro Then

    'read all the fields that has "original agency acronym" in the beginning of its linked excel files.'
    str = ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceName 'Dim str variable above if necessary
    ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = path & "\" & taracro & "_" & Right(str, InStrRev(str, "_")-1)
    'Assign the fields with new links that are created from combining the "target path" ,"target agency acronym", and the parts of the names right after the original acronyms of the original linked file names.'
    msgbox ActiveDocument.Fields(x).LinkFormat.SourceFullName   'does this message show the proper path??
Else
    'Leave other linked fields as they are.'
End If
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```